# can I use GtkTextView widget without gtk_init() / gtk_main()?

Tags: gtk, gtk3, pangocairo

I currently use cairo/pango to generate raw image data from dynamic text. My application is not a Gtk+ GUI app, just a native C++ headless video server. Using dynamic text, I generated raw images for overlays and then alpha blend them over the video streams the server processes and distributes via the network. There is no text editing involved for this text, but given text I generate a corresponding image overlay suitable for alpha blending.

However, I need more formatting flexibility (indents, center alignment, etc). Doing extensive formatting in cairo/pango is painful.

I have been looking at the GtkTextView/GtkTextBuffer API and I think it has easier formatting using GtkTextTag. These widgets obviously have extensive editing capabilities but I only need the formatting capabilities.

Question: can I use GtkTextView/GtkTextBuffer/GtkTextTag **without** running the main gtk+ loop via gtk_init()/gtk_main() ?

Question: how do I get a reference to the raw formatted buffer (cairo image surface or widget pixbuf) **after** all of the tags have formatted the text?

I have been using the gtk_widget_get_pango_context(), pango_layout_new(), gtk_widget_create_pango_layout(), routines but get all sorts of errors because there is no screen.

Edit: Additional Info: what I am trying to do is essentially use only the GtkTextView/GtkTextBuffer/GtkTextTag routines as a sort of standalone library for generating image data of rendered and formatted text.

Thanks,
-Andres

Comment: "Doing extensive formatting in cairo/pango is painful"? Requiring GTK+ as a dependency is also painful. Which is worse? Trying to force a piece of software to do something it's not designed for seems harder to me than either finding something that will do the job easily or using a more difficult piece of software that is designed for the job.

Comment: As a note, I don't want to sound mean with my comment above, but I really think your plan will be very difficult to get working. For that reason, I also don't know if it's possible.

Comment: Short answer is no. GTK needs to be initialised with gtk_init() first. gtk_main() starts the loop, without which the GTKTextView will not get any graphical updates. There probably is a library out there that will do what you want, but that would be a very broad answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically no. You can't use Gtk without init() and/or mainloop(). Why? Because any drawing event is queued and is only drawn in the idle loop. Without mainloop() you don't have any idle time.

On the other hand, you are jumping from low-level drawing in Cairo to Widgets in gtk (which uses Cairo at a low level). There are many intermediate solutions which you could consider. You could generate [Latex](http://www.latex-project.org/about/) and compile it. [Markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) can take of simple formatting. There's HTML of course, where you can even use CSS, and render it to about anything.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion wrt other solutions. That has got me re-thinking my whole approach--thanks